# How to render dynamic data in Flask / Jinja2 / WTForms?

Tags: flask, jinja2, flask-wtforms, wtforms

I'm trying to render a dynamic QR-code in Flask using Jinja2 templating so that the user clicks on a 'Buy Now' button, managed by WTForms, which calls a function to render the payment qr-code.

If I flash the output it does appear as a string so I know the QRGen function is working.

My static variables are all exporting correctly in the render template but if I export `qr1` I get the following error:

> UnboundLocalError: local variable 'qr1' referenced before assignment

I'm guessing that's because the variable is dynamically instantiated. Here is the code:

```
#INDEX.HTML

<form action="" role="form" method="post">
            {{ shopform01.hidden_tag() }}
            {{ shopform01.buy01( type="button", class_="button", id="buybutton01", value="Buy Now") }}
            </form>

{{ qr1 }}

#MODELS.PY

from flask_qrcode import QRcode

def QRGen(id,price):
    nanodress = app.config['NANO']
    buytime = str(datetime.now().strftime("%y%m%d%H%M%S%f"))
    nanoprice = requests.get("https://api.coingecko.com/api/v3/simple/price?ids=nano&vs_currencies=usd").json()["nano"]["usd"]
    bits = "nano:"+nanodress+"?amount="+str(price/nanoprice*0.0000000001)+buytime+id

    def __repr__(self,bits):
        return QRcode.qrcode(self.bits, error_correction='H', fill_color='#802929', icon_img='shop/nano.png')

#ROUTES.PY

from app.models import QRGen

@app.route('/index', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def index():

...

    price01 = 10

    shopform01 = Buy01()
    if shopform01.validate_on_submit():
        qr1 = QRGen("01",price01)

...

return render_template('index.html', title='Home', shopform01=shopform01)
```

Answer (score 0):

In the last line of index function in routes.py pass a `qr1=qr1`

`return render_template('index.html', title='Home', shopform01=shopform01, qr1=qr1)`

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks but it gives me this error: UnboundLocalError: local variable 'qr1' referenced before assignment.

Comment: have you used `qr1` variable in some other files or somewhere else in routes.py. Try to assign `qr1=None` at the starting of index function and then reassign it later in if block